# Code analysis/this, objects and lists

Tags: java

I need some help in understanding the code. I'm struggling with this one.
I'm curious why in output there are one by one values "D15, D10, D5". I understand that we are holding values 'x' on list, but why there is letter "D", which is given in "toString" method. I don't see anywhere, where it is brought on. Is it something with "this" in B.make().add(this)? I'd really grateful if someone could help me.

Output: H1 G0 C B A F15 G0 C A F10 G0 C A F5 C D15 D10 D5 (in new lines)

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mat[][] = {
            {1, 2, 3, 4},
            {5, 6, 7, 8},
            {9, 10, 11, 12}
    };

    try {
        fun(mat, 0, 0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }


    A a = new A(15);
    new A(10);
    new A(5);

    B.make().show();


}

public static void fun(int[] tab, int i, int j){
    for(int k = 0; k<i;k++){
        System.out.print("I"+tab[k]+" , ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static int fun(int[][] tab, int i, int j) {
    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
        System.out.println("H" + tab[i][j]);
        return tab[i][j] + fun(tab, i - 1, j + 1);
    } else
        return 0;
}
}

class A {
int x;
A next;

private A() {
    System.out.println("G" + x);
    B.make().add(this); 
}

public A(int x) {
    this();
    this.x = x;
    System.out.println("F" + x);
}

public A(A objA) {
        this(objA.x - 1);
    System.out.println("E" + x);
}

public String toString() {
    return "D" + x;
}

}

class B {
private static B struct;

public static B make() {
    System.out.println("C");
    if (struct == null)
        struct = new B();
    return struct;
}

private A head;

private B() {
    head = null;
    System.out.println("B");
}

public void add(A obj) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = obj;
    } else {
        A tmp = head;
        while (tmp.next != null) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        tmp.next = obj;
    }
    System.out.println("A");
}

public void show() {
    A tmp = head;
    while (tmp != null) {
        System.out.println(tmp);
        tmp = tmp.next;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No. It is the `B.make().show();` in your main-method. When tmp is printed it's using the toString-method of your class A.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand fully now :)